# Degree of the map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What is a degree of a map $f:T^2\rightarrow T^2$ given by $f(z,w)=(z^2, w^3)$? Is it 5?

Comment: the *algebraic* degree is clearly 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Künneth formula to obtain an explicit form of the fundamental class of $T$ in terms of the two circle factors. Then, use the explicit form of $f$ acting on the two circle factors to conclude that the degree is 6.